# Increase value of textbox by 1 on click in listview in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I am making shopping cart. To populate items I have used ListView. There is option where user can Increase or decrease value by 1 of quantity for particular items in textbox. I am bit confuse what logic should I use here.

OnItemCommand I tried following code but not working.

```
private void cartItemsList_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "incrementButton") {
        try {
            int ID = e.CommandArgument;
            Label mainQuantity = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("quantity");
            mainQuantity.Text = mainQuantity.Text + 1;
            ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("quantity")).Text = mainQuantity.Text;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Response.Write(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Error

> ystem.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label'. at cart.cartItemsList_ItemCommand(Object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)

Cart Snapshot
[image]

Comment: The exception explains it; the 'Quantity' box is not a label, but rather a textbox. Try `TextBox mainQuantity = (TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("quantity");`

Comment: @KeyurPATEL Oh shit man. Such an stupid mistake I have made. Anyways thanks for help :-)